# How to get SQLProvider working on mono with Npgsql?

Tags: f#, mono, npgsql, type-providers

I've created a minimal reproduction here: https://github.com/mushishi78/transaction-minimal-reproduction

Essentially I've hit a `NotImplementedException` given by mono's [`TransactionInterop`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Transactions/System.Transactions/TransactionInterop.cs) that seems to imply that it's not ready for async transactions. But as I'm not that experienced with .NET, I was hoping for some second opinions or advice.

Have I done something odd in the implementation and if I wrote it correctly this would be completely fine?

Should I wrestle with upgrading to a later version of Npgsql even though I had trouble with that originally?

Should I give up on async for the time being because it possible doesn't make as much difference in .NET world?

Should I give up on SQLProvider as other ORM/object mapper libraries don't have these issues (eg. Dapper)?

Would I have better luck not using Postgres as SQL Server is much better supported in .NET world?

Or is it mono that's just not ready for primetime and I'm better off making a server run on a windows box?

#### Code

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open System.Transactions

let [<Literal>] connectionString = "Host=localhost;Database=example;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Enlist=true"
let [<Literal>] resolutionPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"..\packages\Npgsql.3.1.0\lib\net451"

type sql = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,
                           connectionString,
                           ResolutionPath = resolutionPath,
                           UseOptionTypes = true>

let withTransaction fn =
    async {
        use transaction = new TransactionScope (TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
        let ctx = sql.GetDataContext ()
        let! result = fn ctx
        transaction.Complete ()
        return result
    }

let createPerson (ctx: sql.dataContext) =
    let row = ctx.Public.Person.Create ()
    row.Id <- 1
    row.Name <- "Hello"
    ctx.SubmitUpdatesAsync ()

let editPerson (ctx: sql.dataContext) =
    query {
       for row in ctx.Public.Person do
       take 1
    }
    |> Seq.iter (fun row -> row.Name <- "Hi there!")
    |> ctx.SubmitUpdatesAsync

let deletePerson (ctx: sql.dataContext) =
    query {
       for row in ctx.Public.Person do
       take 1
    }
    |> Seq.iter (fun row -> row.Delete ())
    |> ctx.SubmitUpdatesAsync

let run (ctx: sql.dataContext) =
    async {
        do! createPerson ctx
        do! editPerson ctx
        do! deletePerson ctx
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    withTransaction run
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore

    0
```

#### StackTrace

```
  The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetTransmitterPropagationToken (System.Transactions.Transaction transaction) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Transactions/System.Transactions/TransactionInterop.cs:57
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlPromotableSinglePhaseNotification.Enlist (System.Transactions.Transaction tx) [0x00070] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal () [0x0012c] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <301d14fab821450fa5cc07ec7c940a17>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.Sql.connect[a] (System.Data.IDbConnection con, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] f) [0x00009] in <5d776594de6dfdbfa74503839465775d>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.PostgresqlProvider.FSharp-Data-Sql-Common-ISqlProvider-GetColumns (System.Data.IDbConnection con, FSharp.Data.Sql.Schema.Table table) [0x000ae] in <5d776594de6dfdbfa74503839465775d>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.SqlDataContext.FSharp-Data-Sql-Common-ISqlDataContext-CreateEntity (System.String tableName) [0x0001f] in <5d776594de6dfdbfa74503839465775d>:0
  at Program.createPerson (System.Object ctx) [0x00000] in /Users/max/dev2/TransactionMinimalReproduction/TransactionMinimalReproduction/Program.fs:22
  at Program+run@45.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x00000] in /Users/max/dev2/TransactionMinimalReproduction/TransactionMinimalReproduction/Program.fs:45
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.CallThenInvoke[T,TResult] (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncActivation`1[T] ctxt, TResult result1, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] part2) [0x00005] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
  at Program+withTransaction@16-4[a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncActivation`1[T] ctxt) [0x00000] in /Users/max/dev2/TransactionMinimalReproduction/TransactionMinimalReproduction/Program.fs:16
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] firstAction) [0x00020] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncResult`1[T].Commit () [0x0002c] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronouslyInCurrentThread[a] (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation) [0x00028] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.RunSynchronously[T] (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] timeout) [0x00013] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] timeout, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] cancellationToken) [0x0006e] in <039b17603f7a807e0eeaa652dc64c784>:0
  at Program.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in /Users/max/dev2/TransactionMinimalReproduction/TransactionMinimalReproduction/Program.fs:52
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I posted it here: https://github.com/mushishi78/transaction-minimal-reproduction#stacktrace

Comment: better to include the stacktrace here, not externally; btw if I were you I would use EntityFramework, not Dapper

Comment: Thanks. I've posted it in the description now.